# WebStorm is auto downloading JavaScript typings. How to stop this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm

I've installed react-router **v6** but WebStorm still use react-router **v5** types.

In WebStorm folders: `/Webstorm2021.2/javascript/typings/...` has `loadsh`, `react-dom`, `react-router-dom`, `styled-components` libraries. When I remove those typings folders WebStorm auto creates and downloads those four libraries.

Why does this happens and how to stop this? Or let WebStorm choose the v6 types by default?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Experiencing exactly the same problem with typings and `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The IDE downloads typings for some popular libraries to its configuration folder and uses it to enhance code completion. You can remove the auto-downloaded typings from your `<system directory>/javascript/typings` (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) and then either disable `typescript.external.type.definitions` Registry key or remove `react-router-dom` (and other stuff you don't like to be downloaded automatically) from `typescript.external.type.definitions.packages` key

The **Registry** can be located via: **Help > Find action** > type `Registry...`